# Spring oauth2 password flow, how use AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to add handler on user login. In basic spring security it could be implemented by this code:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.
     //some configurations
     .formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
}
```

Unfortunalty, this way do not work with oauth2 password flow because user do not authenticate using login form(there is direct request to *oauth/token* endpoint).
I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34691551/3523298), and wonder is there cleaner way?

UPD: If I use Authentica‌​tionSuccessEvent - I receive this event on every request, Perhaps because I use JWT authentication.

Comment: Hello @dur !, i want to save user last login time

Comment: You could use `org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationSuccessEvent`. instead of `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding about this event! Yeah, i recieve event with listener, but with jwt authentication i receive this event on every request

Comment: I have resource and auth server in one application.

Comment: You can check the instance of `Authentication` to find out, if it is a login with password or with JWT.

Comment: This is how i do it now, wonder is there cleaner way, using success handler

Comment: how can i distinct between login with password or with JWT in Authentication??. i am in the same situation. Authentica‌​tionSuccessEvent fires on every request.

Comment: You can use `@EventListener` to listen `AuthenticationSuccessEvent`